# Does Leaflet has option for scale dependent layers?

Tags: javascript, web-mapping, leaflet

Is it possible to show layers with Leaflet depending on scaling? For example not show counties until zoom level reaches 10.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

yes you can set the scale in the constructor:

for example:

```
var layer = L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.page.com/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg", {
        minZoom: 1,
        maxZoom: 14
    } ) ;
```

vectors don't have max/min properties, you could use a zoomend event to trigger adding or removing them, something like:

```
    map.on('zoomend ', function(e) {
         if ( map.getZoom() > 13 ){ map.removeLayer( vector )}
         else if ( map.getZoom() <= 13 ){ map.addLayer( vector )}
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this possible with L.polygon, not with L.tileLayer? It is, I just try it. Thanks so much!

Comment: I have added a part about vectorlayers

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works which is awesome! Just wanted to add that the method is slightly different from warrieka mentioned. Needs to be - **map.getZoom()** not map.zoom `map.on('zoomend ', function(e) { if ( map.getZoom() > 12 ){ map.removeLayer( vector )} else if ( map.getZoom() <= 12 ){ map.addLayer( vector )} });`